# how to post multiple id parameter with xmlhttprequest from view to controller CI

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

## This is my javascript

```
  var daerah_asal=document.getElementById('daerah_asal').value;
  var daerah_tujuan=document.getElementById('daerah_tujuan').value;
  var jenis_penumpang=document.getElementById('jenis_penumpang').value;

  xmlhttp.open('get', '<?php echo site_url(); >beranda/tampil_tarif/daerah_asal='+daerah_asal, true);
```

## This is my controller

```
public function tampil_tarif($daerah_asal, $daerah_tujuan, $jenis_penumpang){
        $data['daerah_asal']=$this->tampil_tarif_model->ambil_daerah_asal($daerah_asal);
        $data['daerah_tujuan']=$this->tampil_tarif_model->ambil_daerah_tujuan($daerah_tujuan);
        $data['jadwal']=$this->tampil_tarif_model->ambil_jadwal($daerah_asal,$daerah_tujuan);
        $data['jenis_penumpang']=$this->tampil_tarif_model->ambil_jenis_penumpang($jenis_penumpang,$jadwal);
        $this->load->view('modal_tarif',$data);
    }
```

## When i run this code, its error  and show bad request

#### Please help me, thanks

Comment: You appear to be doing a `GET`, not a `POST`.

Comment: `<?php echo site_url(); >` is missing a `?`

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes, i want to get value from id. what shoul i do in xmlhttprequest ??

Comment: @kerbholz i dont know if **?** was needed when use controller..

Comment: `<?php echo site_url(); >` should really be `<?php echo site_url(); ?>`! You also might want to post WHAT error you get.

Comment: @kerbholz yeah, solved, thanks